# UICollectionView how to deselect all

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a FollowVC and FollowCell Setup with collection View. I can display all the datas correctly into my uIcollection view cell  using the following code with no problem.

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("FollowCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? FollowCell {

        let post = posts[indexPath.row]

        cell.configureCell(post, img: img)

        if cell.selected == true {
            cell.checkImg.hidden = false
        } else {
            cell.checkImg.hidden = true
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

Note that I could also select and deselect multiple images using the following code

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if deletePressed == true {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! FollowCell
        cell.checkImg.hidden = false
    } else {
        let post = posts[indexPath.row]
        performSegueWithIdentifier(SEGUE_FOLLOW_TO_COMMENTVC, sender: post)
    }
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! FollowCell
    cell.checkImg.hidden = true
}
```

When In "Select" mode, I can perform the selction of each cell and a check mark will be displayed on the cell. However, what I want to do is to have a cancel buttom to disable all the selected cell and removing the checkImg.

I have tried

```
    func clearSelection() {
    print("ClearSelection posts.count = \(posts.count)")

    for item in 0...posts.count - 1 {
        let indexP = NSIndexPath(forItem: item, inSection: 0)
        followCollectionView.deselectItemAtIndexPath(indexP, animated: true)
        let cell = followCollectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexP) as! FollowCell
        cell.checkImg.hidden = true
    }
}
```

The program crashes here giving me a fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional error at

```
let cell = followCollectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexP) as! FollowCell
```

I dont know why it is having trouble unwrapping the cell to be my FollowCell which contains an instance of the checkImg. I already used it before in a similar situation in didSelectItemAtIndexPath and it seems to work?

Thanks,

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Not all of the selected cells may be on screen at the point when you are clearing the selection status, so `collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)` may return nil.  Since you have a force downcast you will get an exception in this case.

You need to modify your code to handle the potential `nil` condition but you can also make your code more efficient by using the `indexPathsForSelectedItems` property of `UICollectionView`

```
 let selectedItems = followCollectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems
 for (indexPath in selectedItems) {
     followCollectionView.deselectItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated:true)
     if let cell = followCollectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? FollowCell {
        cell.checkImg.hidden = true
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I needed and works. I didnt need to use any reloadItems Code though. I did what you said and it works exactly like you said.

Comment: Or, if you like it more swifty:
`tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows?.forEach({ tableView.deselectRow(at: $0, animated: false) })`

Answer (score 18):

Using Extension in Swift 4

```
extension UICollectionView {

    func deselectAllItems(animated: Bool) {
        guard let selectedItems = indexPathsForSelectedItems else { return }
        for indexPath in selectedItems { deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: animated) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, helped me to implement similar feature in table view.

Comment: or simply `indexPathsForSelectedItems?.forEach{deselectItem(at: $0, animated: animated)}`

Answer (score 5):

To simplify further, you could just do

```
followCollectionView.allowsSelection = false
followCollectionView.allowsSelection = true
```

This will in fact correctly clear your followCollectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems even though it feels very wrong.

Answer (score 3):

```
collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?
    .forEach { collectionView.deselectItem(at: $0, animated: false) }
```

Answer (score 0):

**This answer may be useful in  swift 4.2**

```
 let selectedItems = followCollectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems

 for (value in selectedItems) {
     followCollectionView.deselectItemAtIndexPath(value, animated:true)
     if let cell = followCollectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(value) as? FollowCell {
        cell.checkImg.hidden = true
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved easier by doing this:

```
 tableView.selectRow(at: nil, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableView.ScrollPosition.top)
```